# Recommended (git) repository structure for project files for a viz system

Tags: git, version-control

I should start by saying that i'm a versioning newbie that have tried svn and git.

I am looking for some pointers or advice on how i could version control my work environment. I am using a visualization system that uses many different configs, as in "products that you want to visualize automatically and regularly".

They are all indepentent, and you can think of them as something analogous to a Maya or a 3Dmax project. The visualization system itself is also versioned already, in subversion, but my question regards all our products that run periodically in this system.

These products are saved in their individual folders, with the foldername identifying the product and then a "system.config" xml in there that defines the actual look of the outcome, as well as some not-so-important log file dirs. All of these products are under a dir called "modules"

Now, i would like to version all our products. And we also have a production setup as well as development setups. Ideally i would like to exchange products beween these two environemtns, and they are both in dirs called "modules" in both places.

However, it feels like it would be an overkill to pull the whole production repo down to my development machine... that is, the whole "modules" dir of the production environment. There are around 150 products in there, and most of them are different from what i run on my development machine.

Do you think git can be integrated into this system/workflow, maybe by fetching only certain parts of the repo?

Comment: Each of the 150 different products should be its own Git repo.

Comment: Hehe, that was exactly the answer i wasn't hoping for....  I have a feeling that would be somewhat unmanageable in the long run.

Maybe i should just use SVN instead, as i understand it SVN makes it easy to check out part of a repository.